# Two-Part Hurdle Model Simulation with Bootstrapping

Tags: multithreading, functional-programming, r

I am running a simulation study where I am using two-part hurdle modeling on different effect sizes. I tried to stream-line my code for the best optimization including foreach loops and parallelization. I attempted to post here prematurely a few weeks ago and am now posting my updated code.

I keep running into an error where the hessian matrix is singular that stopped the loops.  I continued the loops and logged the errors (any advice on this would be great). I recognize this is a statistical problem, but often others know more than I.

Any feedback on optimization would be ideal as I am running 1000 resamples and 1000 bootstraps. For 50 iterations and 50 bootstraps, it took 7 minutes. For 500 and 500, it took around 3.5 hours.

```
install.packages("boot")
install.packages("doParallel")
install.packages("doRNG")
library(pscl)
library(boot)
library(doParallel)
library(doRNG)

# if TRUE, keeps a processor free to be used by the OS.
kFlag.free.processor <- TRUE

#Store the path coefficients as a list and a matrix (for different uses)
kParameters <- (function(){

  ##path coefficient vectors
  sizes <- c(50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000)

  seeds.small <- c(51, 53, 55, 57, 58, 59)
  seeds.medium <- c(61, 63, 65, 67, 68, 69)
  seeds.large <- c(81, 73, 75, 77, 78, 79)

  #cbind call will coerce an integer to a vector filled with that value
  c <- .25
  i <- 1
  ##end path coefficient vectors

  effect.small <- cbind(a = .18, b = .16, c, i, n = sizes, seed = seeds.small)
  effect.medium <- cbind(a = .31, b = .35, c, i, n = sizes, seed = seeds.medium)
  effect.large <- cbind(a = .52, b = .49, c, i, n = sizes, seed = seeds.large)

  list(list = list(small = effect.small, medium = effect.medium, large = effect.large),
       matrix = rbind(effect.small, effect.medium, effect.large))#return
})() #IIFE

# RNG MODULE FOR TWO_PART HURDLE MODEL

gen.hurdle = function(n, a, b1, b2, c1, c2, i0, i1, i2){

  x = round(rnorm(n),3)
  e = rnorm(n)
  m = round(i0 + a*x + e, 3)

  lambda = exp(i1 + b1*m + c1*x)                       # PUT REGRESSION TERMS FOR THE CONTINUUM PART HERE; KEEP exp()
  ystar = qpois(runif(n, dpois(0, lambda), 1), lambda) # Zero-TRUNCATED POISSON DIST.; THE CONTINUUM PART

  z = i2 + b2*m  + c2*x                                # PUT REGRESSION TERMS FOR THE BINARY    PART HERE
  z_p = exp(z) / (1+exp(z))                            # p(1) = 1-p(0)
  tstar = rbinom(n, 1, z_p)                            # BINOMIAL DIST.         ; THE BINARY    PART

  y= ystar*tstar                                       # TWO-PART COUNT OUTCOME

  return(cbind(x,m,y,z,z_p,tstar))
}


##################################################################################################
# MODEL ##########################################################################################
##################################################################################################


#model

iterations = 500
r = 500

# capture runtime
system.time({
  ## Setup Parallelization
  message("Setting up Parallelization...")

  # create clusters for each available processor
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1*kFlag.free.processor, outfile="")
  message(paste0("Created ", detectCores() - 1*kFlag.free.processor, " workers..."))

  # register parallelization backend
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  # pass functions and variables from the "Global Environment" to the "master R process" (being run on each processor)
  clusterExport(cl, c("gen.hurdle", "hurdle"))

  message(paste0("Parallelization ready. Reserving ", 1*kFlag.free.processor,
                 " processor for the OS..."))
  ## end Setup Parallelization
  results.all <- foreach(parameters.index = 1:nrow(kParameters$matrix), .combine = rbind) %do%{

    message("Beginning simulation on new set of parameters...")

    n <- kParameters$matrix[[parameters.index, 'n']]
    a <- kParameters$matrix[[parameters.index, 'a']]
    b <- kParameters$matrix[[parameters.index, 'b']]
    c <- kParameters$matrix[[parameters.index, 'c']]
    i <- kParameters$matrix[[parameters.index, 'i']]
    seed <- kParameters$matrix[[parameters.index, 'seed']]

    registerDoRNG(seed) # set.seed() for parallel code

    errors <- 0
    no.zeros <- 0

    results <- foreach(iiii=icount(iterations), .combine = rbind) %do%{

      message(paste0("Iteration ", iiii, " of ", iterations))
      data  = data.frame(gen.hurdle(n, a, b, b, c, c, i, i, i))
      data0 = data.frame(gen.hurdle(n, a, 0, 0, c, c, i, i, i))

      p_0     =1-mean(data$z_p)
      p_0_hat =1-mean(data$tstar)
      p_0_b0     =1-mean(data0$z_p)
      p_0_hat_b0 =1-mean(data0$tstar)

      #power

      fit1      = lm(m ~ x, data=data)
      fit2      = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=data, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")

      a_hat     = summary(fit1)$coef[2,1]
      b1_hat    = summary(fit2)[[1]]$count[2,1]
      b2_hat    = summary(fit2)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
      ab1_hat   = prod(a_hat,b1_hat)
      ab2_hat   = prod(a_hat,b2_hat)

      #type I error

      fit3       = lm(m ~ x, data=data0)
      fit4       = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=data0, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")

      a_hat_b0   = summary(fit3)$coef[2,1]
      b1_hat_b0  = summary(fit4)[[1]]$count[2,1]
      b2_hat_b0  = summary(fit4)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
      ab1_hat_b0 = prod(a_hat_b0,b1_hat_b0)
      ab2_hat_b0 = prod(a_hat_b0,b2_hat_b0)


      message(paste0("Bootstrapping..."))
      # bootstrap
      boot <- foreach(jjjj = icount(r), .combine = rbind, .errorhandling = "remove", .packages = c("pscl")) %dopar%{

        #power

        boot.data = data[sample(nrow(data), replace = TRUE), ]

        has.zero <- prod(boot.data$y) > 0
        if(!has.zero) {
          no.zeros <- no.zeros + 1
          boot.data$y[1] = 0
          warning(paste0("Iteration #",iiii, "  Bootstrap #",jjjj, " had no zeros!"), immediate. = TRUE, call. = FALSE)
        }

        boot.fit1 = lm(m ~ x, data=boot.data)
        boot.fit2 = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=boot.data, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")

        boot.a    = summary(boot.fit1)$coef[2,1]
        boot.b1   = summary(boot.fit2)[[1]]$count[2,1]
        boot.b2   = summary(boot.fit2)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
        boot.ab1  = prod(boot.a,boot.b1)
        boot.ab2  = prod(boot.a,boot.b2)

        #Type I error

        boot.data0 = data0[sample(nrow(data0), replace = TRUE), ]
        boot.data0$y[1] = if(prod(boot.data0$y) > 0) 0 else boot.data0$y[1]

        boot.fit3  = lm(m ~ x, data=boot.data0)
        boot.fit4  = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=boot.data0, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")

        boot.a_b0   = summary(boot.fit3)$coef[2,1]
        boot.b1_b0  = summary(boot.fit4)[[1]]$count[2,1]
        boot.b2_b0  = summary(boot.fit4)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
        boot.ab1_b0 = prod(boot.a_b0,boot.b1_b0)
        boot.ab2_b0 = prod(boot.a_b0,boot.b2_b0)

        cbind(ab1_hat,    ab2_hat,    boot.ab1,    boot.ab2,
              ab1_hat_b0, ab2_hat_b0, boot.ab1_b0, boot.ab2_b0) #return
      } # end bootstrap

      if(nrow(boot)!=r){
        warning(paste0("Iteration #",iiii," threw ",r-nrow(boot)," error(s)"), immediate. = TRUE, call. = FALSE)
        errors <- errors + r-nrow(boot)
      }

      z0.1 = qnorm((sum(boot[,3] > boot[,1])+sum(boot[,3]==boot[,1])/2)/nrow(boot))
      z0.2 = qnorm((sum(boot[,4] > boot[,2])+sum(boot[,4]==boot[,2])/2)/nrow(boot))
      z0.1_b0 = qnorm((sum(boot[,7] > boot[,5])+sum(boot[,7]==boot[,5])/2)/nrow(boot))
      z0.2_b0 = qnorm((sum(boot[,8] > boot[,6])+sum(boot[,8]==boot[,6])/2)/nrow(boot))

      alpha=0.05 # 95% limits
      z=qnorm(c(alpha/2,1-alpha/2)) # Std. norm. limits

      p1    = pnorm(z-2*z0.1) # bias-correct & convert to proportions
      p2    = pnorm(z-2*z0.2)
      p1_b0 = pnorm(z-2*z0.1_b0)
      p2_b0 = pnorm(z-2*z0.2_b0)

      ci1    = quantile(boot[,3],p=p1) # Bias-corrected percentile lims
      ci2    = quantile(boot[,4],p=p2)
      ci1_b0 = quantile(boot[,7],p=p1_b0)
      ci2_b0 = quantile(boot[,8],p=p2_b0)

      sig.ab1 = if(prod(ci1) > 0) 1 else 0
      sig.ab2 = if(prod(ci2) > 0) 1 else 0
      sig.ab1_b0 = if(prod(ci1_b0) > 0) 1 else 0
      sig.ab2_b0 = if(prod(ci2_b0) > 0) 1 else 0

      #results
      cbind(sig.ab1, sig.ab2, sig.ab1_b0, sig.ab2_b0)
    } # end iterations


    mean.results <- t(apply(results, 2, mean))

    colnames(mean.results) <- c("power of ab1", "power of ab2",
                                "type I error of ab1", "type I error of ab2")
    cbind(t(kParameters$matrix[parameters.index, ]), mean.results, errors, no.zeros)
  } # end parameters loop
  # release cores back to the OS
  stopCluster(cl)

  View(results.all)
}) # end System.time
```

Please tear me apart as I love to learn and am relying on your wisdom. Also, realize I am fairly new to R/Programming.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of style / minor performance improvement comments. I believe it will take someone with statistical knowledge of the model you are using to help you more:

- `message()` and `warning()` will concatenate strings if provided with multiple arguments so no need for `paste0()` here. **Note that excessive verbosity might slow down your program because too much resources are used to print messages.**
- when working with scalars, it is better/faster to use `*` rather than `prod`.

```r
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({prod(10, 11)}, {10*11}, times = 10000)
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>                 expr min  lq     mean median  uq  max neval
#> {     prod(10, 11) } 394 413 461.8892    430 456 7903 10000
#>      {     10 * 11 } 204 221 242.8107    228 241 4206 10000
```

- as far as I can tell, you can drop the following lines because you're not using them:

```r
p_0     =1-mean(data$z_p)
p_0_hat =1-mean(data$tstar)
p_0_b0     =1-mean(data0$z_p)
p_0_hat_b0 =1-mean(data0$tstar)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this. I had no idea that ```message()``` and ```warning()``` functioned like that. Also, a very good point about less is more for printing.

I meant to comment those lines out. I do not need them. Another great catch.